# scala spark to read file from hdfs cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am learning to develop spark applications using Scala. And I am in my very first steps. 
I have my scala IDE on windows. configured and runs smoothly if reading files from local drive. However, I have access to a remote hdfs cluster and Hive database, and I want to develop, try, and test my applications against that Hadoop cluster... but I don't know how :(

If I try

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("hdfs://masternode:9000/user/hive/warehouse/dwh_db_jrtf.db/discipline")
```

I will get an error that contains:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "MyLap/11.22.33.44"; destination host is: "masternode":9000;
```

Can anyone guide me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SBT to package your code in a `.jar` file. `scp` your file on your Node then try to submit it by doing a `spark-submit`.

```
spark-submit \
--class <main-class> \
--master <master-url> \
--deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
--conf <key>=<value> \
... # other options
<application-jar> \
[application-arguments]
```

You can't access to your Cluster from your Windows Machine in that way.

Comment: I said I am using "Scala IDE" ... I am not asking about running on the command line

Comment: This is how are deployed Spark applications. You have the answer : "runs smoothly if reading files from local drive" -> hdfs://masternode:9000/ is not local. But you seem to know good so...